# Zathura synctex-editor-command cannot open some editors such as VS Code

Tags: zathura, visual-studio-code

The document reader Zathura supports synctex forward and backwards search when working with LaTeX documents. The backwards (from Zathura to the editor) search is set through the `--synctex-editor-command` flag or `set synctex-editor-command` in the `zathurarc` config file.

I cannot get the backwards search to work when I set the `synctex-editor-command` to run Visual Studio Code. For example, I

```
set synctex-editor-command "code --reuse-window -g %{input}:%{line}"
```

and Ctrl+click the document does not do anything.

The setting works with some other editors, for example with

```
set synctex-editor-command "gvim --remote-silent +%{line} %{input}"
```

and it works. Even with something simple like

```
set synctex-editor-command "gedit"
```

(or `"gvim"`), Ctrl+click would open the specified editor (with a black document) as expected, but not with the command `"code"`.

The man page for Zathura says that the functionality works via the D-Bus interface, which I don't know anything about.

Is it possible to fix this on my side?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (with `zathura 0.4.5` as provided by the repo), but a quick trial on the Fedora liveboot suggests that it's the same there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--no-sandbox` will solve it.

Try with `zathura -x "code --no-sandbox -r -g %{input}:%{line}" your_file.pdf`.

Configuration for latex-workshop VSCode plugin:

```json
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.command": "zathura",
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.args": [
        "--synctex-editor-command",
        "code --no-sandbox -r -g %{input}:%{line}",
        "%PDF%"
    ],
```